# How update value in redux reducer if it's inside of object

Tags: reactjs, redux

if i have a state in my reducer like:

```
let initialState = {
  data: {
    name: ''
  },
};
```

how i can update `name` value with `action.payload` ?
i tried these things but it's giving syntax error.

```
 case SET_NAME:
      return { ...state, data.name: action.payload };
```

and :

```
   case SET_NAME:
              return { ...state, state.data.name: action.payload };
```

what i need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `spread` operator

```
const newState = {
    ...state,
   data:{
       ...state.data,
       name: action.payload
   }
}
return newState
```

Comment: . why newState ?

Comment: It's easier to understand. But you can just `return` directly like you're doing

Comment: yes it's worked. thank you, But have more optimized way so without make some constant and return it ? so just return  ...state,
   data:{
       ...state.data,
       name: action.payload
   }